# Suggestion for fetch the data in database and set progress bar

Tags: react-native, progress-bar, react-native-sqlite-storage

I have already stored the student id and number of books read in the database. now, I have implemented the method to get the details of books count read by the students. but the function progressbardata() doesn't return the data fetched from query. I have tried to assign a value manually inside the db.transaction() and returned it but no luck.

Could you please let me know where i am doing wrong. also this method looping multiple times. how can we sort this out.

```
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
var db = openDatabase({ name: 'UserDatabase.db' });
let progressbardata = (id) => {
    var totalItems=0;
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM student where id = ?', [id], (tx, results) => {
          totalItems = results.rows.item(0).percent;
          return (totalItems);
      })
    })
}
const _renderContent = (item, index) => {
return (
<View>
   <Progress.Bar color='#68FF33' progress={progressbardata(item.id)}/>
   </View>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the request to fetch the data is asynchronous and this code does not seem to wait for a response to continue. Therefor the code would continue while the fetch requests has not returned a value yet. If this is the case, I would suggest that you let the request set the State of the component, and make the state the input of the Progress.Bar component. This way, when the fetch requests finishes asynchronously, the state will be set and the progress bar will be updated. This would look something like this:

```
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
import { useState } from 'react'
var db = openDatabase({ name: 'UserDatabase.db' });

const renderContent = (props) => {

    [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)

    let progressbardata = (id) => {
            var totalItems=0;
            db.transaction((tx) => {
                  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM student where id = ?', [id], (tx, results) => {
                  totalItems = results.rows.item(0).percent;
                  setProgress(totalItems);
              })
            })
        }

    progressbardata(props.id)

    return (
    <View>
       <Progress.Bar color='#68FF33' progress={progress}/>
       </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I am using state it doesn't work. because I want to pass each student id and get the data.

Comment: @Ashok so you want a progress bar for each student id? I am not sure if this even is a functional component, but even in functional components you can pass in the id as a prop and still have progress bars for each student id

Comment: Yes. I have passed each student id to the function and get the data. sorry I am really new to the react native and not sure, how I will achieve. Could you please give me some example to achieve this.

Comment: I have added a sample of what it would look like. now renderContent is a component that can be used like this: '<renderContent id={student.id}/>' and should display a progress bar of the student from which the id is entered as props. maybe this link can help you more to understand everything that is happening: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html